# Linux automount corrupts ext4 partitions of Android install?

Tags: boot, linux, file-system, partitions, ext4

I've been experimenting with dual-boot between Linux and Android on an x86 device which came with Android + Windows preinstalled (Chuwi Hi10 Pro).

I soon found out that simply booting Ubuntu (either from a live USB stick or from the on-device install) will kill the Android installation (hangs at boot), to the point that only a factory restore will help.

The reason seems to be that Ubuntu automounts every ext4 filesystem it can find, including the Android partitions (system/data/cache/config). I've fixed this by adding the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
# do _not_ automount the Android partitions
UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b  /none ext4 ro,noauto 0 0
UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b1 /none ext4 ro,noauto 0 0
UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b2 /none ext4 ro,noauto 0 0
UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b3 /none ext4 ro,noauto 0 0
```

I'm now wondering about two things:

1. What is it that Ubuntu can possibly do to the ext4 partitions that will later cause Android to hang on boot?
2. Could this be related to the fact that apparently all Android partitions share the same UUID?

EDIT: as suggested by mook765, here's the output of `lsblk -f`:

```
NAME         FSTYPE LABEL     UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0                                                            
├─mmcblk0p1  vfat   ANDROIDIA 1389-AFF9                            /boot/efi
├─mmcblk0p2                                                        
├─mmcblk0p3                                                        
├─mmcblk0p4                                                        
├─mmcblk0p5                                                        
├─mmcblk0p6                                                        
├─mmcblk0p7  ext4             57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b 
├─mmcblk0p8  ext4             57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b 
├─mmcblk0p9  ext4             57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b 
├─mmcblk0p10                                                       
├─mmcblk0p11 ext4             57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b 
├─mmcblk0p12 vfat             8A7A-6F97                            
└─mmcblk0p13 ext4             9dadc784-4ed1-4e54-adec-8227b73a0777 /
mmcblk0boot0                                                       
mmcblk0boot1
```

Note that this is an intentional duplicate from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092142/ubuntu-automount-corrupts-ext4-partitions-of-android-install.